# jquery datepicker set date on year or month select

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've got a datepicker that works fine, the only missing thing i want is to set the date in the input when the user picks a year or a month. Currently it just set's the date when you pick the day. I want this because the user may think the date is getting changed with just selecting one of those (year or month) and I don't see anything on the docs that refers to that part of the picker.

Comment: Could you include any of the relevant code to help us better understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think I see what you want, but don't understand "...the user may think the date is getting changed with just selecting one of those..." Can you clarify?

Comment: @JasCav Selecting the year and month. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code. It will *change current date if user selects a different month or year*. In case I misunderstood your question please let me know so I can adapt my answer!

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
            var curDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            if (curDate == null)
            return; 
            if (curDate.getYear() != year || curDate.getMonth() != month - 1) {
                curDate.setYear(year);
                curDate.setMonth(month - 1);
                $(this).datepicker("setDate", curDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As I am quite new to JQueryUI and JQuery at all, let me know if there is something to improve!

Answer (score 2):

So, there are two things you need to do.

First, you need to allow the user to change the month and year. That can be done with the changeMonth and changeYear properties being set to true. By doing this, it also enables access to the changeMonthYear event, which will respond to the changing of the month and year. So, your final code will look something like this...

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            $(this).val(month + "/" + year);
        }
    });
});​
```

Here is an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHvM3/).